# How much xp is a lightsaber worth?

Tags: experience-points, star-wars-force-and-destiny

I'm new to the star wars force and destiny role game. While reading through the rules on page 322 of the core rulebook I found the following statement:

> PCs uninterested in lightsaber combat should have the opportunity to obtain something comparable, such as additional XP to invest in Force powers or specialization trees.

I haven't found a guideline on how much experience would be balanced instead of a lightsaber. I understand it's probably not an exact number but I need some order of magnitude. 10? 50? 100?

Answer (score 5):

I'm new here so this is my first answered question, but I've played FND for the past 3-4 years.

TL;DR: **Edge Studio does not to my knowledge specify that XP**, my gut reaction if I were making this decision would be ~40XP but it's up to you and I provide ways you could work out what your own decision is for this particular campaign is.

I don't recall an exact XP amount for lightsabers, it's up to you as GM, but 30-50XP is arguably reasonable for the given reasons below, and if you want an exact number, 40XP is a happy medium.

Elsewhere in I think Edge of the Empire, lightsabers are talked about as quest rewards, so if you want to strictly mechanics it, you could say that a given gameplay session is 15-20XP per session, then multiply that by how many sessions a given quest to go make or obtain a lightsaber would be (2-3 for side quests, 5+ for main quests, again, up to you), then grant that character that amount of XP.

Since the FND character creation gives most padawans ~120XP and a lightsaber, so if a character has not invested that time in learning lightsaber combat they have trained elsewhere, so an additional 30-40 XP gets them closer to starting knight level play, which is 150XP if I recall correctly, (though you should still only spend the first ~120XP or so on characteristics) so for these characters who have focused more on the force and their spec trees, they have more time to spend there as opposed to having done basic lightsaber forms training.

I would not necessarily advise giving more than 50-75XP, lightsabers are amazing, but they don't make you all powerful, and the difference between a 120XP character and 220XP character is quite stark in Star Wars FFG, depending on playstyle.